# Prettier keeps replacing asterisk characters with underscores

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, markdown, prettier

I'm trying to write some markdown text in Visual Studio Code and whenever I write this:

```
*some text*
```

It's being replaced by this as soon as I save the file:

```
_some text_
```

I narrowed it down to be caused by the Prettier extension. I tried looking for a setting that might control this but didn't find any - well none that was obvious to relate to the issue.

I'd really like to keep Prettier enabled for markdown files as it also keeps tables nice and tidy.

Is there a way around this one issue?

UPDATE:

I am aware that both asterisk and underscore works for italic emphasis when the file is shown through a markdown viewer, but when reading the file as pure text, the asterisk feels more natural to me for emphasis and I'd much prefer keep using it if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also feel the same way, but from what I can tell Prettier simply does not have that option (https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)

> Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish. It is opinionated.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html

Given that philosophy, I doubt this will ever change. As for me, I think I'm going to try to just get over it.

I think the only way to avoid this would be to use something different, for example:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint

Comment: At the moment, the relevant code in Prettier is here: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/678de02/src/language-markdown/printer-markdown.js#L138-L158 and here: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/main/src/language-markdown/printer-markdown.js#L138-L158 (2nd link points to `main` branch, line numbers may drift out of sync over time, or file may be renamed etc.)