# Is there a way to change Prettier markdown italics to asterisk?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, prettier

I've been trying to find a way to change Prettier's markdown italics setting to asterisk instead of underscore but to no avail. Having the underscore as the default is problematic if it is surrounded by other characters; even from https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/ the advise is to use asterisks.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to change this, the Prettier docs doesn't have any info about this either.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prettier keeps replacing asterisk characters with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052818/prettier-keeps-replacing-asterisk-characters-with-underscores)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to how [markdownlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint) reformats your markdown file in VSCode on save/format, this is what I use to force asterisks for italic:

```json
"markdownlint.config": {
  "MD049": { "style": "asterisk" }
}
```

Comment: [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) is a different tool.